# How to share a variable in 'joblib' Python library

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def func(v):
    temp.append(v)
    return

temp = []
Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(func)(v) for v in range(10))
print temp
```

I want to make shared memory variable. But the value of temp is empty []. How can I do it?

For other method, I tried pickle.dump and load. But there is a lock problem. Please give me advice!

Comment: i think it would be `Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(func(v)) for v in range(10))`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thank you for comment. Your command has a error. "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`multiprocessing.Manager.list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), for example:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from multiprocessing import Manager

manager = Manager()
temp = manager.list()

def func(v, temp):
    temp.append(v)
    return

_ = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(func)(v, temp) for v in range(10))
```

`temp[:]`:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I doesn't run like that anymore. Move `def func...` to after the imports, everything else inside `if "__name__" == __main__:`. Then import `freeze_support` and call it (it's a function) right after the `if` line.

Comment: What do you mean @JannPoppinga by "it doesn't run like that anymore"? I've tried it and it works. Do you have a specific version of a library in mind?

Answer (score 11):

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def func(v):
    return v

temp = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(func)(v) for v in range(10))
print temp
```

`delayed` collects the output returned by `func` in a list and returns it on completion.